# I can't figure out UIScrollView and content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

My `UIScrollView` keeps bouncing back when I run the app. I have read many, many other posts about people having trouble with their scroll views, and the solution is always to set `contentSize`. I've retried it many times but it never seems to work.

I must be missing some fundamental aspect of scroll views or Objective-C but this is what I have done/checked so far:

- Scrolling is enabled.
- Bounce and Bounce Vertically are enabled.
- My scroll view is connected to `levels` in the outlet tab.
- I've named my scroll view "levels".
- I set my content size to a huge number `(4000, 9000)`

All I have so far is ViewController.h and ViewController.m, below:

Here is my H.

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property IBOutlet UIScrollView *levels;

@end
```

Here is my M.

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize levels;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [levels setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [levels setContentSize:CGSizeMake(4000, 9000)];
}

@end
```

Any ideas as to why it's not working?

Comment: Have you confirmed levels is not nil on viewDidLoad?

Comment: Try to set a delegate for the scrollview and set a breakpoint in scrollViewDidScroll to see when the offset changes.